# Added mathjax-rails to load mathml in chrome but not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mathjax, pmml

I found this git repo https://github.com/pmq20/mathjax-rails and followed the steps to add Mathjax in my rails application.

I added this line to the Gemfile:

`gem 'mathjax-rails'`

and then:

`$ bundle install`

added the following to `config/routes.rb` :

`mathjax 'mathjax'`

add the script tag inside app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

`<%= mathjax_tag %>`

I also loaded this configuration file `Accessible-full.js`:

`<%= mathjax_tag :config=>'Accessible-full.js' %>`

But looks like I need to also enable the CMML plugin in mathjax and I do not know how. Or I need to preprocess the mml to just deliver the pmml portion. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you restarted the server?

Comment: @DimitriusLachi just realised that I haven't, so I did, and I edit my initial question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart rails server after bundle install

Comment: Just realised that I don't get the error anymore after restarting rails server, but I don't see any change, the math formulas are being shown the same as before